# Регулярное выражение ,как написать?

Tags: php

При добавлении комментария должна быть проверка на запрещённые слова: «лес, поляна, озеро», она не должна срабатывать на слова которые содержат в себе эти слова, к примеру она не должна сработать на слово «лесной», проверка должна быть регистр независимой.

Comment: https://regex101.com/r/K8n6IG/1? В ссылке внизу слева есть кнопка code generator, это позволит увидеть пример в коде

Comment: @Хетаг а зачем такая проверка нужна? В реальной жизни бунтари найдут способ обойти проверку (например заменив "е" на "e" в слове "лeс"). А если это учебное задание, то где ваша попытка (код) решить его?